# Export xml string to dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, dataframe

I have an XML string of the type:

```xml
<data> 
  <header> 
    <name>a</name> 
  </header> 
  <row> 
    <Date>2021-04-20</Date> 
    <Name>One</Name> 
    <code>15689</code> 
    <code2>Y</code2>
    <code3>38</code3>
  </row>
  <row> 
    <Date>2021-04-20</Date> 
    <Name>Two</Name> 
    <code>16890</code> 
    <code2>Y</code2>
    <code3>92</code3>
  </row>
</data>
```

And I am trying to parse this in a pandas data frame using this method:

```py
dfcols = ['Date','name','code','code2','code3']
etree = et.fromstring(xml_str)

#xml_str is the xml string of the type mentioned above
rows = etree.findall('.//row')

xml_data = [[i.get('date'),i.get('name'),i.get('code'),i.get('code2'),i.get('code3')] for row in rows]

df = pd.DataFrame(xml_data, columns=dfcols)
print(df)
```

As a result, I get a data frame full of `None` values.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pandas v1.3 (estimated release by end of May 2021), the new [**`read_xml`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html#pandas.read_xml) makes this even easier with either `lxml` or `etree` parser:

```py
df = pd.read_xml("Input.xml", xpath=".//row", parser="etree")
```

Comment: You won't believe how eager I am for `read_xml` to be available...

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. Just change

```
rows=etree.findall('.//row)
```

to

```
xml_data =[]
for row in etree.findall('.//row'):
    xml_data.append([element.text for element in row.findall('.//*')])
```

Output:

```
         Date name   code code2 code3
0  2021-04-20  One  15689     Y    38
1  2021-04-20  Two  16890     Y    92
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help! That way I am only able to input only the first row on the data frame. I tried to iterate by columns and it didn't work. Do you have any pointers as to how to get all the rows ? Thank you!

Comment: @Anna, this solution parses all children of all `<row>` nodes.